# how to convert a "linq to sql" DataContext to write to flat XML files?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have use linq to sql in my windows application it works fine, but now due to some reason I want to remove that *sql server database* & instead of it I want to use **XML files** as data storage. what i have to do *without doing much more changes in my C# code.*

In my project i have done something like this..

Initially i drop n drag all my sql database table in .net frame work here i get a q.dbml file of my database & i am accessing that like

```
DataContext dc = new qDataContext();         
var v = from emp in dc.employees where emp.id == 1 select emp;
```

Is there any method to replace that sql server database with XML without doing much more changes in my project coding?

Comment: The only relationship between LINQ to SQL and LINQ to XML is the word "LINQ". They don't work similarly in any way. Among other things, LINQ to XML is not an XML database system.

Comment: why? why would want to change from SQL to XML as a data store?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I hope my edit clarifies things.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ADONET_and_XML.aspx

Comment: @Merlyn That helps him generate the XML files I guess, but it still involves work. Not to mention he still has to rewrite his CRUD operations...

Comment: @ErOx: I don't really know how Linq to SQL works, and didn't expect the sample code to work directly.  I just figured if that worked, that maybe there was an ado.net provider for some sort of XML DB, in which case he could just plug it in.  Also: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2004/09/18/231185.aspx - maybe Linq to SQL doesn't work this way tho?

Answer (score 1):

You are barking up the wrong tree.

This is the reason for the Repository Pattern; separating the data access layer from the rest of the application logic, so that (for example) the backing store can be changed easily, by switching the repository implementation.

Since you have not done that... you are stuck with manually altering your code. LINQ to SQL is not able to be "converted" to LINQ to XML; it just won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the ***why*** you would want to do this...

No. There is no method of switching from a SQL Server Database to XML files that is not going to involve a lot of changes to your code.

As others have pointed out, LINQ to SQL and LINQ to XML are not the same things. LINQ to SQL relies on a context object that knows how to connect to your database, how to read tables, etc. There is no equivalent concept with generalized XML files. At the very least, you will have to rewrite the data access portion of your project.